# Accuracy different between mean square method and reduce mean

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I try to calculate the accuracy for the learning rate in the neural network. I am using mse method and reduce mean method. But both is giving a very different accuracy figure. Can someone please advise me?

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y - output, 2))/(2*n_samples)
optimizer = optFunction(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

prediction = tf.equal(tf.cast(output,tf.int32), tf.cast(y,tf.int32))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(prediction, tf.float32))

mse = cost2.eval({x: X_train, y: y_train})
acc = 1-np.sqrt(mse) 
print (" Acc = ", acc)
print ("Acc = ", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dic={x: X_train, y: y_train}))
```

The resullt is 89% for mse method and 70% for accuracy. Is there something wrong with the algorithm?

Comment: mse = cost2.eval({x: X_train, y: y_train}) is actually mse = cost.eval({x: X_train, y: y_train}). typo error

Comment: You can [edit] your question if needed...

Comment: I don't understand this question at all, what do you mean computer accuracy for the learning rate? And what is 1 - sqrt(mse)? What does your network do? (regression or classification)

Comment: This is a classification. After, I calculate the mean square error. I need to use the mse to calculate the,accuracy in percentage. Please help me if the algorithm is wrong. Thank.